# Run docker nvidia container with GPUS and systemctl

Tags: docker, containers, nvidia-docker

when trying to run systemctl along with GPU,

systemctl is not working without --privileged and when trying to limit GPUS by providing `--runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 --privileged` the container shows all the GPUS available inside the container.

if --privileged is not specified `--runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` the container shows the desired amount of GPUs

Answer (score 0):

NV_GPU='GPU number' nvidia-docker run  --runtime=nvidia -it -v path:path nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:xx.xx

Example:

```
NV_GPU='0,1' nvidia-docker run  --runtime=nvidia -it -v /storage/research/:/storage/research/ nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:17.11-tf2-p3
```